# Exception handling in R, no matter from which functions it comes from

Tags: r

I wrote an app in r with shiny.

In this app the user need to add a data set's and choose several options in radio buttons.

But unfortunately if the combinations of the chosen radio buttons and his uploaded data sets aren't fit (for example his data sets are gene expression of potato and he click on the tomato button) it show me an error.

How can i catch the exception no matter from where it come from. i don't want to wrap functions.
If i will get an exception for example "argument 1 is not a vector". I want it will replaced to "the combinations of data set and chosen Plant Type are not fit".

Answer (score 3):

Wrap areas that you are worried may fail in `tryCatch()`.  You can use the `finally` argument to gracefully handle errors (such as printing the appropriate error message to the page).

See `demo(error.catching)` for some good examples of how to deal with errors.